# State-of-the-art unification for associative-commutative functions

Tags: pl.programming-languages, term-rewriting-systems

I am interested what are the open problems on unification methods for associative-commutative functions, and what is the state-of-the-art work? I have found [some](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322262) [old](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-10009-1_25) [work](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-10009-1_25), but nothing new. I am wondering if I am missing something since I am quite new to this.

It might help to say that I am generally interested in this area as I would like to apply it to modern programming languages, in terms of code canonicalization.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the 581 articles citing this one?  http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=3988217028093045034

Comment: I have, but I can't say I found what I need. It is hard for me as a newbie to distill relevant papers from such a big pile. I thought maybe there is someone who works on this and who can provide some overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the standard references on unification:

- Franz Baader and Tobias Nipkow. Term Rewriting and All That. Cambridge University Press, United Kingdom, 1998. ([Book homepage](http://www4.in.tum.de/~nipkow/TRaAT/))
- Franz Baader and Wayne Snyder. Unification Theory. In J.A. Robinson and A. Voronkov, editors, Handbook of Automated Reasoning, pages 447-533. Elsevier Science Publishers, 2001. ([Online copy here](http://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/research/papers/2001/BaaderSnyderHandbook.ps.gz))